# Is there is any other backup for Nifi other than template and flow.xml file?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

i have  been using Nifi-0.6.1.
My entire workflow has been crashed while running processors.While check logs it shows permGenSpace error.So i have increase the heap memory and permgen space in Bootstrap file.

After that i can't able to run nifi. So i have looking for backup my workflow.

Is Nifi have any other backup for entities in UI other than following two?

1.Template.
2.Flow.xml.gz

i.).I have forget to save my entire workflow as template.

ii.)I think flow.xml having my entire workflow so try to open the flow.xml.gz file it shows error which is in below screenshot.
[image]

But flow.xml has been unzipped.It having some not enclosed tags.It shows like below.,

[image]

How can i back to my entire workflow?.

**If backup operation(flow.xml.gz) doesn't worked then how can i get workflow in which used in Nifi UI?.**

If i delete "flow.xml.gz" then nifi running correctly.But my entire workflow has lost.

Comment: Is there anything under conf/archive? I know more recent versions of NiFi auto-archive the flow periodically to conf/archive, but I am not sure if that was happening in 0.6.1. Also, when you say you increased the memory and permgen and it won't start, are there any errors in nifi-bootstrap.log or nifi-app.log?

Comment: Thanks @BryanBende There is no folder archive under conf in the version nifi-0.6.1. Actually the log files contains the error(Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream), since the flow.xml was not saved properly. How to get archive folder backup in the version 0.6.1?? Is there is any other way to backup the complete workflow other than flow.xml.gz??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nifi now has built in version management through the [Nifi Registry](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.5.1/getting-started-with-nifi-registry/content/downloading-and-installing-nifi-registry.html)

This also makes it easy to safeguard your flow, and it can even integrate with Git if more functionality is needed.